# How to verify AutoSar TSYNC?

Tags: autosar

I'm working on Adaptive AutoSar tsync module.

Now I'm trying to find the way how to verify tsync library between ECUs.

But I don't have any idea of verifying tsync library.

If anyone is able to know how to verify tsync library from time synchronization, Please let me know

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by *"verify tsync library"*

Comment: "verify tsync library" means to check time synchronization between ecu. Adaptive Autosar tsync library is designed for synchronizing time between eco.

Comment: Can you verify the timing of output of each ECU against each other?

Comment: Could you please let me know the reference code about the timing of output ??  I don't know how I can implement test-code to check the timing.

Answer (score 0):

You can call now() function periodically from the different ECUs and see if the values are matching.